# Question about double brackets for boolean condition (possibly Java)?

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style, compiler-warnings, conventions

I have a vague memory of my professor from way back ~10 years ago saying that it would be a good practice to write conditions which check a boolean value, with double brackets, unless if you specifically check if it is `true` or is `false`.

So instead of

```
if(isColdOutside) {}
```

You should do

```
if((isColdOutside)) {}
```

And the reason is that if you do single-bracket, the compiler is going to issue a warning to tell you that maybe you forgot to check the value, since there is no `==` in the condition. So by using double-brackets, you tell the compiler "This is what i meant to do, just check if this is truthy".

He mostly taught Java stuff, that's why I thought it might be a Java thing.

But now, I wanted to look for it, and I can't find anything about this. I tried searching for variations of stuff like "double bracket condition" or "boolean condition warning", and I got no significant results.

Does this syntax/convention have a name? Is it even real, or did I just dream it?

Comment: I don't get a warning from single parentheses around boolean variables..  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Well, I'm not getting any warnings, that reason i provided was just from memory of what i think my professor had said

Comment: Not adding `==true` when using a boolean variable in a condition is actually considered a good practice by QA tools like Sonar

Comment: Only time I've ever used inner brackets is if im separating conditionals out between `&&` and `||`

Comment: Not only is it not necessary, it's an actual bad idea -- because it's not standard, and therefore the reader has to stop and think about it: *Why has he written ```if ((foobar))``` rather than ```if (foobar)```?  Is there something missing?*

Answer (score 2):

After 20 years of working with Java I have never heard of this.  I don't think it is a thing.  And if it is a thing, then no one I know would think it was something other than a typo.

Other languages like the Bash shell in linux have multi-bracket differences, but Java, not so much.